# return a SUM zero(0) instead of null

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

```
SELECT SUM( IF( userId = '123456', amount, 0 ) ) AS 'amount'
FROM `amountInfo`
```

userId `123456` is not present in table `amountInfo`, in that case it is returning null i want 0(numerical)

Comment: [COALESCE(expression1, expression2, ... , expressionN)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalesce for this

**UPDATE** : I was missing the argument to set 0 instead of NULL, pointed by @Barmar

```
coalesce( SUM( IF( userId = '123456', amount, 0 ) ),0 )
```

Comment: You're missing an argument to `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 2):

Use IFNULL:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IF(userId = '123456', amount, 0)), 0) AS amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Select COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount from amountInfo where userId='123456'
You can read on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp